# Is there a way to sort the jest coverage table by % of covered lines?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, vue-cli

When running jest tests with coverage in my Vue cli project, it outputs a nice table at the end.

Is there a way to sort that, so I can see at glance which files have the least %-Lines coverage?